# Programmatically add fillable form fields to PDF file

Tags: command-line, bash, pdf, adobe-acrobat, forms

I regularly need to create PDFs with fillable form fields that can then be filled using Adobe Reader. However after a lot of research, it seems that the only tools capable of actually adding fillable  form fields to PDFs are GUI tools like Acrobat and Foxit, which are also often proprietary. Note that I'm not asking for tools that programmatically fill out those form fields, of which it seems there are many - I'm asking for the inverse.

How can I add fillable form fields to my PDF files programmatically, either via the command line or some other method, such that I can more easily automate the process?

Comment: Do you have a PDF with forms link ? That will be handy to test what is possible or not

Comment: Give a try to this perl module: https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF Ex: `$doc->fillFormFields($name => $value, ...)`

Comment: @GillesQuenot Unfortunately, the PDFs are sensitive so I can't provide examples. That said there's nothing out of the ordinary about these PDFs so there's no reason why a working solution wouldn't also work on a sample PDF like [this](http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf) or [this](http://www.aloaha.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/SampleForm-1.pdf).

Comment: @GillesQuenot I may be missing something, but CAM::PDF doesn't seem to have any functionality for creating form fields, just filling them in.

Comment: Isn't this an oxymoron?  You want pdf files fillable by Adobe Reader, which essentially means they must be created with propriety Adobe software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pymypdf might be an option to programmatically generate pdf documents.

https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF

https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/blob/master/fields/form-fields.py

However, it seems to have issues

https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/3180

Comment: Accepted since this is the closest to an answer this question has gotten in 3 years. From what I can remember I also came across [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.org/) and [qpdf](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf), though I can't remember off the top of my head whether they supported form fields.

Answer (score 3):

If it MUST be "free of cost", you'd have to look around the usual suspects (aka PDF-creating libraries); there may be some solutions available.

Otherwise, the best possible tool (because it has the widest range of JavaScript methods and properties) is Acrobat Pro. Period.

For very simple forms, you might also look at the Forms Design module of LibreOffice (but you still may need Acrobat, even if it is just for debugging your forms).

Comment: I was afraid of Acrobat effectively being the only tool with which this can be done programmatically. Which "PDF-creating libraries" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of **bulk filling a PDF** with fields is that they only need to be text so taking the first offered example in the FDF we add the data. You dont need to add ALL fields just those you wish to fill OR alter.

```
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<< /FDF << /F (OoPdfFormExample.pdf)
/Fields [<<
/T (Address 1 Text Box) /V (Hello World!)
>> <<
% ... other data fields if wanted

/T (Family Name Text Box) /V (Aziz)
>> <<
/T (Favourite Colour List Box) /V (Red)
>> <<
/T (Gender List Box) /V (Man)
>> <<
/T (Given Name Text Box) /V (Hashim)
>> <<
% ... other data fields if wanted

/T (Language 5 Check Box) /V /Off
>> <<
/T (Postcode Text Box) /V (AB12 3CD) 
>>]
/ID [<5E0A553555622A0516E9877CA55217A6> <5E0A553555622A0516E9877CA55217A6>]
/UF (OoPdfFormExample.pdf)
>>
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

Now we can use that file (try it with http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf but may need to tidy up my % ... comments to a cleaner file) it is as simple as **double click FDF** and it opens the PDF with that data. We do need to ensure the form is trusted first. (Simple to set to "Always")

[image]

Now anytime we open the FDF with the different field of data is is auto inserted into the Template. We simply need to overwrite FDF data before open and save the PDF with a new name.

[image]

### Answer

That Acrobat function is costly compared to the command line cross platform PDFTK which is under $30 for the server license. But it does use an older syntax based on V-1.2 ?

An alternative is use a modern low cost command Line SDK like Tracker PDF-Xchange (the free one will work too) which can also command line open FDF and SAVE as PDF and is about twice the price of PDFTK.

### Slooower Freeway

Route the data into a file like HashimAziz.FDF
Open Acrobat Reader with the blank one
Load AcroRd32 HashimAziz.FDF
Use VBA or its sendkeys to trigger a "Save As" and feed in "HashimAziz"
{Shift+Ctrl+S} (will depend on method) WAIT 500 {Enter} WAIT 500 HashimAziz {Enter}
Then "Loop" for the next FDF
END Loop
Send {Alt+F4}

[image]

Potential hurdles are that FDF as text needs care when the field in a template were not sized correctly as there can be different issues with fields that are too small for potential content, especially Unicode.

Whic is the other point that PDF does not use UTF-8 in the conventional way. so we need to consider hexencoding or use ANSI like this

```
>> <<
/T (Given Name Text Box)
/V (þÿG'4E)
>> <<
```

Which if done correctly will then fill an enlarged field like this, (so it should be even bigger).

[image]